# Moving from RelayCommand to ReactiveCommand

Tags: reactiveui, relaycommand

I am in the process of learning ReactiveUI and I am starting with commands

I have trouble translating the code for this RelayCommand to the equivalent ReactiveCommand

```
GodkendeBilagCommand = new RelayCommand<AdminUdbetalingsKvartal>(OnGodkendeBilag, GodkendeBilagCanExeute);
```

this is the code for GodkendeBilagCanExeute:

```
private bool GodkendeBilagCanExeute(AdminUdbetalingsKvartal kvartal)
{
    return kvartal != null && kvartal.KanGodkendeBilag && !IsBusy;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var canExecute = this.WhenAny(x => x.kvartal.KanGodkendeBilag, x => x.IsBusy,
    (bilag, busy) => bilag.Value && !busy.Value);

GodkendeBilagCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(canExecute);
```

Comment: Looks nice but the kvartal is a command parameter and not a property on the viewmodel. I have taking a look at Rx test code and I can't find a test where the command parameter is used.

Comment: The command parameter is intentionally not used because it is an Antipattern in ReactiveUI

Comment: Can you explain to me why it's an AntiPattern? I have INotifyPropertyChanged on many of my domain objects, shame on me (-: and it reduces the amount of code I have to write for simple CRUD forms. If I don't have command parameter how can I then edit a list of customers without putting a command on each customer domain object?

Comment: Is there ANY way to have a command parameter passed to the `CanExecute`? Say I have a calculator or another board with many buttons, might even be dynamic, and I want a single command to be bound to them all, having the parameter be statically in the button and pass on as parameter, does that mean I need separate command for each button? Any other ideas?